# Matrix Completion on 98% sparse Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I have an application where the client would like to do matrix completion based on a matrix that is 98% sparse.  I have a data set where the matrix is 2.2 million cells.  It has values for 50,000 of those cells.  Is it possible to train an ALS model and reliably fill in the other 98% of the cells or is that just not possible.  I am seeing people fill in 8% -12% but nothing close to the percentage I am looking at.  I am not interested in technically how to do it but if it would even be feasible

Comment: Maybe this question should better be asked on [cs.stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour)? It's not really a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the (I expect unknown) rank of your underlying matrix. If it has rank 1 and if I assume that your 2.2 millions cell matrix is square this matrix has about 3000 degrees of freedom, which means that knowing 50000 cells is way enough information. Up to rank 15 your information might be sufficient and trying to fit a model is at least not absurd.